# How to differentiate yum fresh installation and yum update?

Tags: linux, rpm, yum

I am trying to upgrade a package using RPM. How would I know whether it is a fresh installation or update. IS there any flag which I can check or should I write a script to check whether it is fresh installation or upgrade?

Comment: could you clarify your question? What (kind of) command do you perform? What kind of output would you expect? What do you get?

Comment: I have a software version 8.10 installed. Am trying to install the latest 8.18 on top of it. Is there a means to find whether it is upgrade scenario or fresh installation scenario through some flag or by writing a script?

Comment: @Chris Maes, Please let me know if my question needs some more clarity or you got my problem?

Comment: it is still not very clear to me. You run `yum install package-8.18` and after that you want to know whether that was a clean install or update?
Or do you want to manage something in the `%post` section of your package when it is a clean install only?

Comment: I already installed 8.10 using yum install. Now I wanted to do yum update for 8.18 version. Is there any means to know if 8.18 is getting installed as part of yum update (upgrade) or yum install(first time)  I wanted to handle the code differently for upgrade and first time installation.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question well; I suppose you package `package` yourself?

If you want other actions to happen upon the first install or during upgrade; I suggest you do use the `%post` triggers in you spec file where you can differentiate:

```
%post
if [ $1 -eq 1 ]; then
    echo "this is the first installation"
else
    echo "this is an upgrade"
fi
```